# How do I focus UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift4

I want to implement functions like **radio buttons**. More specifically, I want to implement the ability to select only one `UIView` from several `UIView`s. This is similar to the [Focus  Engine](http://devsign.co/notes/custom-focus-effects-in-tvos) on **tvOS**.

[image]

While searching of relevant this, I noticed that `UIKit` supports [Focus-based Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/focus-based_navigation). But I am not sure if this supports exactly what I want. There is also a lack of additional relevant examples.

I would like to hear some help and advice on related features. Is the **Focus-based Navigation** suitable for the purpose I was pursuing? And are there any other good ways to implement the functionality I want to implement?

Comment: Do you just want the button that is tapped to "jiggles to show selection?  You need to do that yourself; apply an animation when your view is in the selected state and ensure that selecting a button deselects the others.

Comment: @Paulw11 I would like to create a function that clears the rest of the `UIView` when I select the `UIView`. A function that summarizes and selects only one `UIView`. I do not know exactly what "Jiggle" you are talking about. In conclusion, I would like to know if Focus-based Navigation is suitable for the function I want to implement.

Comment: It still isn't clear exactly what you are trying to achieve. There is no focus engine on iOS like there is on tvOS as it doesn't really work for a touch interface. The "jiggle" I was referring to is the movement when the green circle is selected.  You can write whatever code you want to achieve your desired outcome, including hiding other elements. If you are just taking about creating a radio button type of control then there are open source libraries that you might like to use or you can make your own.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your kindness. If so, is `Focus-based Navigation` suitable for selecting only one `UIView`? I do not understand exactly what `Focus-based Navigation` does.

Comment: @Paulw11 For example, assuming there are three UIView circle shape, I tap the first UIView and shadow the first UIView. Again, if I tapped the third UIView instead of the first UIView, the shadow of the first UIView will disappear and a shadow will be created in the third UIView that you just clicked on.

Comment: Focus-based navigation works on the tvOS because you use the track pad to move the focus around the screen and then click on the control you have focused.  You don't need that on iOS since you can just tap directly on the control you want.  You can easily write code that deselects the other button when you select another one. You probably want to create a `UIView` subclass that implements your control.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've seen support for iOS in **Focus-based Navigation** documents. So, I had difficulty understanding. Thank you very much indeed for explaining this. If the selected button is deselected, I must remove the shadow. If so, should I redraw the `UIView`? Or is there a way to partially update the drawing for `UIVIew`?

Comment: Each circle will be a `UIView`; It is up to you to add and remove  shadows as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Paulw Thank you for your kind help.

The following steps solved the problem!

I have used a simple way that effects a specified `UIView` among multiple `UIViews`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectView: UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        selectView = self.view

        let viw = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 150, height: 150))
        viw.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        viw.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.view.addSubview(viw)

        let objectView = ObjectView()
        objectView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        objectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        self.view.addSubview(objectView)

        let tapObject = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
        objectView.addGestureRecognizer(tapObject)

        let tapObjects = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
        viw.addGestureRecognizer(tapObjects)

        let tapRootView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRootView)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .ended {
            if selectView != self.view {
                selectView?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            }

            selectView = sender.view

            if selectView != self.view {
                sender.view?.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
                sender.view?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
                sender.view?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```